# MPD ignoring music_directory specification in config

Tags: debian, configuration, mpd

I have been struggling with MPD for several hours now. I have referenced nearly every post that has been made on the issue of MPD failing to detect the music directory properly and have made no progress. In my configuration file, I have specified `'music_directory'` as both `/home/user/Music` and as `~/Music` several times in different methods, I have completely removed and purged mpd and reinstalled it twice, deleted all old configuration files, and remade these configurations. The only thing that has solved my problem is moving the music library to `/var/lib/mpd/Music` despite this not being the specified music directory. I don't want to have to resort to using this as a solution, as my I have `/home` on a separate partition and dont want to waste my limited space in the system partition

mpd config

```
db_file "/home/user/.mpd/db"
log_file "/var/log/mpd/mpd.log"

pid_file "/var/run/mpd/pid"
music_directory "~/Music"
auto_update "yes"
user "mpd"
```

Any help would be appreciated I'm at my wits end

Answer (score 0):

The music_directory needs to point to an absolute path, for instance:

/home/thisuser/Music

Comment: I've tried using an absolute path for music directory, does not solve the issue